# Why am I getting LazyInitializationException when using OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter? (using Spring Roo)

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-security, spring-roo, lazy-initialization

I've generated my project using Spring Roo and has not touched the xml files.

All I'm trying to do is to get a collection through a ITD method of an entity.

I get the following error:

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet MyProject threw exception
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collect
ion of role: com.myproject.main.domain.Juser.securityRoles, no session or session
was closed
```

Please guide me. I'm stuck badly.

Comment: Are you using the class `com.myproject.main.domain.Juser` for authentication? Are you logged in when the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Lazy init in hibernate is where it loads relationships on demand instead of at query time.
This is often more efficient as it means the main query is simpler.

Sometimes you need to force the loading of the lazy relp's before the session is closed.
In this case, you just need to call a method on the relp objects just after the query to load them completes.